# When running the app on simulator, it crashes and say thread 1: breakpoint 3.1. What should I do?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multithreading, breakpoints

I am new to programming and am trying to do an app right now. The problem started when I tried to make a Google Sign in button, and when I thought I had acheived that, I tried the simulator and none of my buttons worked when clicking on them, not even the text squares. Then the simulator started to crash with the code Thread 1: SIGABRT. I read on some place that you could do an exeption break point to see where the problem is, and when I did that I came to some lines, where on one it said Thread 1: Breakpoint 3.1.

```
import UIKit
import Google

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBOutlet weak var signinbutton3: GIDSignInButton!

@IBOutlet weak var signinbutton: GIDSignInButton!

func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {

}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Sign in presented")
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
            dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Sign in dismissed")
}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self); //this line is where the Thread 1: Breakpoint 3.1 was.


}

}
```

My problem shortly:

**- The buttons on the simulator does not work**

**- The simulatior crashes and show on xcode the code sequence I showed before with the saying Thread 1: SIGABRT and Thread 1: Breakpoint 3.1 in the last line.**

What do you think the problem is and how should I solve it?
**Edit**
I recieve this when trying to start the simulator:

> objc[22047]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   (0x113a45cc0) and
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
>   (0x11385c6f0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>   2017-06-13 21:49:25.051 Startifyapp[22047] 
>   [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been
>   configured. Add [FIRApp configure] to your application initialization.
>   2017-06-13 21:49:26.013 Startifyapp[22047:788392] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Receiver () has no segue
>   with identifier 'loginView''
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf6eb0b **exceptionPreprocess + 171  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010d2ab141 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e00bef3 -[UIViewController
>   shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 0     3   Startifyapp
>
>   0x000000010b971fbf
>   *TFC11Startifyapp14ViewController13viewDidAppearfSbT* + 127   4   Startifyapp                         0x000000010b972021
>   *TToFC11Startifyapp14ViewController13viewDidAppearfSbT* + 49  5   UIKit                               0x000000010e00ecae
>   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 704    6   UIKit                               0x000000010e00f6d4 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 197
>     7   UIKit                               0x000000010dfe1f94
>   -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 868    8   UIKit                               0x000000010e1f6525 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController
>   transitionDidFinish:] + 44    9   UIKit
>
>   0x000000010dfe5af6 __56-[UIPresentationController
>   runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183    10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010e995d1c -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext
>   completeTransition:] + 102    11  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010dfdeec0 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] +
>   251   12  UIKit                               0x000000010dfdeb38
>   -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1408    13  UIKit                               0x000000010dfe1208 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] +
>   104   14  UIKit                               0x000000010def2257
>   -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 222  15  UIKit                               0x000000010def2796
>   -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 136  16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001151a968e
>   _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 306    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001100f305c _dispatch_client_callout + 8     18  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x00000001100d440b _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411    19 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf33909
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bef9ae4 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2164    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bef9016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406   22  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000111775a24 GSEventRunModal + 62   23  UIKit
>   0x000000010de66134 UIApplicationMain + 159    24  Startifyapp
>   0x000000010b9700d7 main + 55  25  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000011013f65d start + 1  26  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Comment: Are you sure, your segue has the correct name in InterfaceBuilder? Also, why would you perform a segue in viewDidAppear?

Comment: Do not forget to call `super.viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: I have the segue in ViewController because that is where Google developer told me to have it. I pasted super.viewDidAppear() in the View controller with the override func viewDidAppear but it gave the red warning sign. Where should I put it?

Comment: I think your problem is with these two: `@IBOutlet weak var signinbutton3: GIDSignInButton! @IBOutlet weak var signinbutton: GIDSignInButton!` Maybe test those out.

Comment: Okay thanks! but what should I do with them? I did just how you are supposed to do a segue, by dragging from the button to the viewcontroller holding ctrl and naming them, how is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Xcode 9 and the simulator.
I used a real device with iOS 11 and it was working fine (with some bugs though)